# crash using YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api, fragment

I have an activity that extends from a fragment

```
public class Youtube_visor extends Fragment{ ...
```

and a method that creates a new YouTube player using YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

This is my code:

```
public void playVideo () {

        fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment player = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentz, player); // fragmentz es un linearlayout que hay en el xml
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        player.initialize(Static_generals.youtubeKey,new OnInitializedListener() {

            public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0,
                    YouTubePlayer arg1, boolean arg2) {
                if (!arg2) {
                    arg1.cueVideo("3OhGkg_XT3o");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                // Error
            }
        });
    }
```

This works perfectly on the tablet, I have an activity with two fragments, left a list of videos, and right, the fragment which create the YouTube player

My problem is I do not want to create a new YouTubePlayer, I want to declare one in the xml and always use that.
This is the fragment declared in the xml:

```
   <fragment
      android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
      android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Now, in my code, I replace this line:

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment player = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
```

and put this new line:

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment player = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
```

but always crash.
I searched for information about it but there is not much available, or have not found it :)

What am I doing wrong?

I guess I'm calling my fragment wrong, because when I do a new one working properly

I appreciate any help.

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: quite old question, but maybe do you remember: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you've put a `YouTubePlayerFragment` in your XML, but you're trying to cast it to a `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` in the code. Try replacing this line:

```
android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
```

With this:

```
android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
```